# i make testing api for website by using jmeter and there is error message so i want solution for this problem

Tags: api, testing, jmeter

I make  api testing for website by using jmeter and there is error message so i want solution for this problem  where i put the base url, path, and write  the parameters then choose linster >>view tree result

[image]

so this image included my error message

Comment: What did you do to get the error? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help answer

Comment: file:///C:/Users/SGM/Desktop/777.PNG

Comment: just i filled all parameters ,make http rquest , and put url and path in their fields

Comment: Can you provide the inputs? Or at least the URI, the error says your URI is wrong

Comment: you have unnecessary `[` and `]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you put the whole URL into "Server Name or IP" field like:

[image]

which is **wrong** as you cannot have anything but [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) or DNS [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) in the "Server Name or IP" field, so you need to split your URL like:

[image]

or put everything into "Path" field like:

[image]

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send at least relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header.

More information: [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

[image] i knew my mistake you should put every part of url in it's place so there is port field and i put the number of port in the field of url so when i divided it , it works successfully
 so this image show that

Answer (score 0):

you should separate port number on server id to work successfully
where there are specific places for each part of url 
 https://medium.com/@chamikakasun/rest-api-load-testing-with-apache-jmeter-a4d25ea2b7b6